# Adding numbers to each node in data.tree

Tags: r, tree

I have the following tree:

```
 library (data.tree) 
    data (acme)
    t1<-acme
    > acme
                              levelName
    1  Acme Inc.                       
    2   ¦--Accounting                  
    3   ¦   ¦--New Software            
    4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards
    5   ¦--Research                    
    6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        
    7   ¦   °--New Labs                
    8   °--IT                          
    9       ¦--Outsource               
    10      ¦--Go agile                
    11      °--Switch to R
```

I would like to enumerate the tree nodes name by adding the number of line to each node name as followed:

```
> t1
                          levelName
1  Acme Inc._1                       
2   ¦--Accounting_2
3   ¦   ¦--New Software_3
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards_4
5   ¦--Research_5                    
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line_6        
7   ¦   °--New Labs_7      
8   °--IT_8                          
9       ¦--Outsource_9              
10      ¦--Go agile_10             
11      °--Switch to R_11
```

Comment: Please give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610)

Comment: Hi @Jaap. If you use library (data.tree) you will be able to use the example data(acme). It is in the package.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We could use `Get` to traverse the tree, collect the `name` and concatenate (`paste0`) from 1 to `totalCount` along the way. Then use `Set` to traverse the tree and assign value:

```
acme$Set(name = paste0(acme$Get("name"), "_", 1:acme$totalCount))
print(acme)
```

Which gives:

```
#                        levelName
#1  Acme Inc._1                       
#2   ¦--Accounting_2                  
#3   ¦   ¦--New Software_3            
#4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards_4
#5   ¦--Research_5                    
#6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line_6        
#7   ¦   °--New Labs_7                
#8   °--IT_8                          
#9       ¦--Outsource_9               
#10      ¦--Go agile_10               
#11      °--Switch to R_11
```