# Assigning Static Number / Character Vector to Nodes in data.tree

Tags: r, tree, hierarchy

I created a data.tree and now I want to add a specific number of the nodes such that.. Oh leave it, I will give example......

`CEO

2    ¦--CXO                         N-2

3    ¦   ¦--HOD                     N-3

4    ¦   ¦   ¦--Manager             N-4
5    ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦--Resource        N-5

6    ¦   ¦   ¦   ¦--Resource        N-5`

You see how the alphanumeric coding changes as the node change.

You can use the original acme dataset to give this out to me.

`library (data.tree)
data(acme)`

As I did research, I found `Node$Set`, probably it has something to do with assigning characters/numerics to nodes, but sadly I am unable to figure out how.

```
# node$Set(..., 
#          traversal = c("pre-order", "post-order", "in-order", "level", "ancestor"),  
#          pruneFun = NULL, 
#          filterFun = NULL)
#traditional:
Set(nodes, ...)
```

Please note I have found similar question, but it adds incremental value to every node instead of giving values to specific node and also understand I want to add alphanumeric...

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462650/5785085

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/33462650/5785085

Comment: This is not duplicate, as this caters in giving string based number to each node while the one you referred adds incremental numbers. @CIAndrews